# PATCH with Alamofire (swift 2.3)

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire, patch

I have a problem, i try to update with PATCH method using Alamofire, but no changes are reflected.

I Think in one of those I am making some mistake.

This is my code:

```
    Alamofire.request(.PATCH, url, parameters: ["op": "replace", "path": "/IsVacinated", "value": true], encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            Utils.endRequest(progressView)
            if let data = response.data {
                let json = JSON(data: data)
                if json != nil {
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                    print(json)
                }
                else {
                    print("nil json")
                }
            }
            else {
                print("nil data")
            }
    }
```

I hope you can help me, and that I have searched and not much information.

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a custom encoding and send your parameters as a raw string in the body

```
let enconding: ParameterEncoding = .Custom({convertible, params in
                let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as? NSMutableURLRequest
                mutableRequest?.HTTPBody = "[{\"op\" : \"replace\", \"path\" : \"/IsVacinated\", \"value\":true"}]".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
                if let mutableRequest = mutableRequest {
                    return (mutableRequest, nil)
                }
                let error = NSError(domain: "Custom", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
                return (convertible.URLRequest, error)
            })
```

Finally using the custom encoding

```
Alamofire.request(.PATCH, url, parameters: [:], encoding: encoding)
        .responseJSON { response in
            Utils.endRequest(progressView)
            if let data = response.data {
                let json = JSON(data: data)
                if json != nil {
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                    print(json)
                }
                else {
                    print("nil json")
                }
            }
            else {
                print("nil data")
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 and Alamofire 4.6 example:

```
struct CustomPATCHEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        let mutableRequest = try! URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest, with: parameters) as? NSMutableURLRequest

        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters!, options: .prettyPrinted)
            mutableRequest?.httpBody = jsonData
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return mutableRequest! as URLRequest
    }
}

func updateProfile() {
    let phoneString = self.phone.value
    let formattedPhoneString = phoneString.digits
    var parameters : Parameters = ["email": self.email.value,
                                   "first_name": self.firstName.value,
                                   "last_name": self.lastName.value,
                                   "id": self.id.value]

    if formattedPhoneString.count > 0 {
        parameters["phone"] = formattedPhoneString
    }

    Alamofire.request(APPURL.Profile,
                      method: .patch,
                      parameters: parameters,
                      encoding: CustomPATCHEncoding(),
                      headers:APIManager.headers())
        .debugLog()
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                break
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.PUT` instead of `.PATCH`

> The difference between the PUT and PATCH requests is reflected in the way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the resource identified by the Request-URI. In a PUT request, the enclosed entity is considered to be a modified version of the resource stored on the origin server, and the client is requesting that the stored version be replaced. With PATCH, however, the enclosed entity contains a set of instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the origin server should be modified to produce a new version. The PATCH method affects the resource identified by the Request-URI, and it also MAY have side effects on other resources; i.e., new resources may be created, or existing ones modified, by the application of a PATCH.

Also, Check is server receiving request from your app is correct or not. Check for URL, Parameters, format and call type. If all things is correct, check for response data.

Comment: The webservice does not allow to use the method PUT, but I am not allowed to modify it. :( ... thanks anyway.